# How one can distinguish between the usage of "gern" (or "gerne" for this matter) as "gladly" and as "like to"?

Tags: grammar, translation

I’ve answered this question, *How one can distinguish between the usage of "gern" (or "gerne" for this matter) as "gladly" and as "like to"?*, in the Duolinguo thread for the sentence

> *Wir würden gerne Ihre Wohnung durchsuchen*

which is translated there as

> *We would like to search your apartment*.

but my question remains unanswered.

My question arised because, in Duolinguo, until this question was put to translation, the site uses *gern(e)* mostly as *gladly* or *like(ing)*, as in *Ich höre gern(e) Musik* (*I listen **gladly** to music*, or, *I **like** listening to music*). On the other hand, we have *Wir würden gern(e) Ihre Wohnung durchsuchen* (*We would **like to** search your apartment*, in oposition to *Wir würden Ihre Wohnung durchsuchen*, as *We would search you apartment*).

I don’t know if it is a translation problem, something about the conjunctive II that I haven’t grasped yet, or that I’m just too limited to get the German subtleties, but to me there is a difference to both meanings, one being doing *something gladly, or with pleasure* (I like to), and the other as *a polite form for asking something* (I would like to), both using the word *gern(e)* in German. Anyway, I would apreciate immensely your answers.

Comment: Is there a difference? In any case, the police would hardly say so, as it sounds like a polite request that could simply be refused.

Comment: How do you differentiate when “I would like to” means “I would enjoy to” and when “Please, I want to”?

Comment: I don't understand the question. "We would gladly search..." - "We would like to search". Where's the problem?

Comment: Can you please edit your question such that the first part is less confusing (what did you do on Duolingo) and the question body contains the titular question?

Comment: I've edited it a bit. Hope it makes clearer for you to understand my question. Again, many thanks for the answers and commentaries.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The word *gerne* is an adverb expressing, that the subject likes to do something, or he/she/it does it *gladly*. But the translation with *gladly* is not common in English, it doesn’t sound natural.

> Ich höre Musik.

means depending on context: *I listen to music* or *I’m listening to music*. It doesn’t imply if you like to do it or not, you are now hearing to music. The word *gerne* specifies, that you like doing it.

> Ich höre gerne Musik.

which literally means *I listen gladly/willingly to music*, but no one speaks in English like that, the meaning is simply *I like listening to music*. One cannot translate between languages like 1:1, word by word, it doesn’t work in 9 of 10 cases.

> Wir würden Ihre Wohnung durchsuchen.

It is difficult to say what this sentence exactly means without context. It translates literally to: *We would search your apartment*.

> Wir würden gerne Ihre Wohnung durchsuchen.

The *würden gerne etwas machen* construct expresses a polite wish to do something. I would do it, gladly and willingly, if you allow me/if it possible etc. This combination of conjunctive and *gerne* is commonly used to express polite wishes:

> Hallo, ich *hätte gerne* einen Hamburger mit Cola und Pommes.
>
> Ich *würde gerne* wissen, woher du kommst.
>
> Ich *wüsste* nur zu *gern*, ob sie seine Freundin ist!

*Nur zu gern* means *I’d **really** love to know …*, *I am **so** curious about …*

There is even another usage of *gern*, somewhat difficult to grasp for learners:

> - Danke!
>
> - Gerne!

This is short form of *gern geschehen!*, literally meaning *happened with pleasure/I was glad to let it happen*. In English nobody would ever say this. You’d rather say *You’re welcome.*

Another example is using *gern* in sentences in imperative mode:

> Komm gerne rein!

This is a shorter form of saying

> Ich hätte gern, dass du reinkommst.